Pandoc and MikTeX
I'm using Windows 10 and MikTeX 2.9. If I install Pandoc into the same system, are both clause? Need advise in this regard.

pandoc is just a program for convert  document formats, including something to latex or latex to something. MikTeX is a TeX distribution to make  tex/latex/context files and more. They are very different hairy beast that can live separately or together in the same ecosystem.

Thanks a lot, if you convert your comment into answer, I'll accept it

Mostly plagiarized from the manual page description:
Pandoc
Pandoc  is  a  Haskell library for converting from one markup format to another, and a command-line tool that uses this library.
Pandoc can convert between numerous markup and word processing formats,including, but not limited to, various flavours of Markdown, HTML, LaTeX and Word docx.
Pandoc can also convert these formats to PDF using external tools. By default, pandoc will use LaTeX to create the  PDF ,  which  requires  that  a  LaTeX engine be installed.
Alternatively, pandoc can use ConTeXt, roff ms, or  HTML  as  an  intermediate format. You can control this with the --pdf-engine  option to use pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex, latexmk, tectonic, wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint, pagedjs-cli, prince,  context,  and  pdfroff  (Note that some of these tools as wkhtmltopdf have nothing to do with MikTeX or another TeX distribution).
Warning: One should not expect perfect conversions between every format.   Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but not formatting details such as margin size.  And some document elements, such as complex tables, may not fit into pandoc’s simple document model.  While conversions from pandoc’s Markdown to all formats aspire to be perfect,  conversions from formats more expressive than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy.
MiKTeX
MiKTeX is a free and open-source distribution of the TeX/LaTeX typesetting system. It is what you need to type in LaTeX, or ConTeXt, or plain TeX and more (Metapost for graphics, for instance), but it is mostly agnostic about Pandoc and non-tex formats.
Conclusion
MikteX is everything you need to write in LaTeX, and it is a free-living creature, it can live on its own.
Pandoc can also live alone and is all you need to convert between some formats such as HTML to Word, or Word to HTML, but it can do more into symbiosis with other tools,  especially MikTeX or another TeX distribution. So, of course, it's perfectly fine to install both, even on Windows.
